# FetchError: invalid json response body at reason: Unexpected end of JSON input when using mockfetch with Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, fetch

I am using Mockfest to test a very simple api for unsplash.
The fetch call works very well of course and it looks like this:

```
test('it makes a fetch call to unsplash', async () => {
        await api.fetchPhoto('wedding')
        expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

and it shows from the Jest script:

● it makes a fetch call to unsplash

```
FetchError: invalid json response body at  reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

  4 |
  5 |     const response = await fetch(url)
> 6 |     const data = await response.json(); 
    |                  ^
  7 |     
  8 |     return data;
  9 | }
```

This is my fetch function:

```
async function fetchPhoto (event) {

    const url = 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?query='+event+'&per_page=1&client_id=gKEeCzK-8XXRBG8IHbYAGTEUDMN-Dpm9FjxjDS4f2Y0';

    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json(); 
    
    return data;
}

module.exports = { fetchPhoto };
```

How can I get past this error, I mean my fetch function works and returns
what its supposed to return.

Answer (score 3):

`response.json()` tries to parse the body of the response as JSON, like `JSON.parse()`.

Generally this error means the response you got is not properly formatted JSON. You can inspect it by `console.log()`, and parsing the body as text using `response.text()` first to see what format it has or what the issue is.